# NSDictionary objectForKey IPhone simulator and IPhone device

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, nsdictionary

I have this function  `return [remoteObject objectForKey:key];` which should return an object that is in my dictionary.

When I am starting the Iphone simulator everything is fine and it returns the right object.
But when I am starting the same application an my device my application crashes and it says SIGABRT
and

> 2011-12-05 10:25:17.601 iPhoneXMPP[242:1a1f] -[CALayer objectForKey:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4f3d40 2011-12-05
>   10:25:17.602 iPhoneXMPP[242:1a1f] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CALayer
>   objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4f3d40'

My key is an Id (17) and it is also in my dictionary.

Does anybody of you knows why this happens only on my device?

Comment: show us how do you init the dictionary and how do you create the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that your `remoteObject`object is being deallocated somewhere. Usually autoreleases happen faster on the device because it has less memory than the simulator that's why on the simulator your object is still there when you are trying to call it's method. Make sure you call `retain`on your object when you created it and `release` when you are done with it.

Comment: Hi. I tried to retain the object but now I have an EXT_BAD_Access error mesg

Comment: Ok, I could figure it out. The objects in the dictionary were also released. So I had to retain them, too.